# Arduino stucks and serial.println outputs are massed up

Tags: c, encryption, arduino-ide, cryptocurrency, iota

I am trying to create an iota transaction bundle in C for Arduino devices and created therefore a github repository:

https://github.com/Xplosio2/Iota-transaction-in-C

The code is compiling successfully, however the Arduino is making some encrypted outputs that doesn't make any sense. I am not able to limit the problem to one file, due to lack of knowladge in c. I suspect that the problem could be in the following files:

kerl.h, kerl.c, conversion.h, conversion.c

I hope you can help me with this problem. Thanks for any help in advance.

PS: I am using the Arduino IDE to compile the code. I think it could be a pointer/stack problem?

Comment: I have investigeted more and now I know that the function kerl_absorb_trit in the kerl.c isn't working. When I comment the function for testing everything works fine. Can anyone help me?

Comment: espacially when I call the keccak_update in the function kerl_absorb_trit